# PIX captures get stuck and never finish on dedicated GPU

Tags: directx

I'm trying to make a capture with my dx11 application, but for some reason PIX gets stuck waiting on some request 'GpuCaptureWinTakeCaptureRequest' and never begins the capture. The application is meanwhile running happily without interruptions. Posting output from PIX:

```
02/25/22 18:42:06.6655:  Waiting for GpuCaptureWinTakeCaptureRequest...
02/25/22 18:43:36.4008:  13652 2>   00007FF67446B971 C:\Program Files\Microsoft PIX\2108.18\WinPixEngineHost.exe!000000000000B971
02/25/22 18:43:36.4008:  13652 2>   00007FF67446C300 C:\Program Files\Microsoft PIX\2108.18\WinPixEngineHost.exe!000000000000C300
02/25/22 18:43:36.4008:  13652 2>   00007FF67446A1EB C:\Program Files\Microsoft PIX\2108.18\WinPixEngineHost.exe!000000000000A1EB
02/25/22 18:43:36.4008:  13652 2>   00007FF67449CCD7 C:\Program Files\Microsoft PIX\2108.18\WinPixEngineHost.exe!000000000003CCD7
02/25/22 18:43:36.4008:  13652 2>   00007FF674490ABC C:\Program Files\Microsoft PIX\2108.18\WinPixEngineHost.exe!0000000000030ABC
02/25/22 18:43:36.4008:  13652 2>   00007FF67448E623 C:\Program Files\Microsoft PIX\2108.18\WinPixEngineHost.exe!000000000002E623
02/25/22 18:43:36.4008:  13652 2>   00007FF674486B6E C:\Program Files\Microsoft PIX\2108.18\WinPixEngineHost.exe!0000000000026B6E
02/25/22 18:43:36.4008:  13652 2>   00007FF67447965D C:\Program Files\Microsoft PIX\2108.18\WinPixEngineHost.exe!000000000001965D
02/25/22 18:43:36.4008:  13652 2>   00007FF67447C70B C:\Program Files\Microsoft PIX\2108.18\WinPixEngineHost.exe!000000000001C70B
02/25/22 18:43:36.4008:  13652 2>   00007FFCB44B2150 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll!0000000000062150
02/25/22 18:43:36.4008:  13652 2>   00007FFCB44A315A C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll!000000000005315A
02/25/22 18:43:36.4008:  13652 2>   00007FFCB3107034 C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL!0000000000017034
02/25/22 18:43:36.4008:  13652 2>   00007FFCB44A2651 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll!0000000000052651
02/25/22 18:43:36.4008:  E_PIX_USER_CANCELED (0x8abc0072: User canceled this request)
02/25/22 18:43:36.5429:  GpuCaptureWinTakeCaptureRequest returned HRESULT: E_PIX_USER_CANCELED (0x8ABC0072) User canceled this request
02/25/22 18:43:36.5499:  GpuCaptureWinTakeCaptureRequest completed after dialog displayed, hr = E_PIX_USER_CANCELED (0x8ABC0072) User canceled this request
```

If when creating my d3d11 device in the application I use the onboard graphics the capture works, but if I use the dedicated GPU it gets stuck. I feel like PIX is getting confused by the presence of two GPUs somehow - I don't see a setting related to this. In the monitor it uses the onboard graphics as well, which is suspicious. Any tips are welcome.

Comment: I have the same problem on D3D12

Comment: I think I found a temporary solution: I checked the "Launch Suspended" option and then "GPU Capture" is able to work once. I hope they can fix this issue in future